# Prevent JSscrollPane from resizing when adding JTextArea/JTextPane populated with text

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

Hello people on the internet

My problem is that when I call `setViewPortView(textArea)` on the `JScrollPane` with the `JTextArea` already having text in it, the `JScrollPane` resizes to fit the entire text of the `JTextArea`.  I would rather want the scroll pane to remain the same size while having the rest of the text hidden in the scroll pane below, so that I can scroll down to see the rest of the text.

See the below example that should be ready to run:

1. Click on the "Edit" button. The `JTextPane` is now replaced with a `JTextArea` which is editable.
2. Type into the `JTextArea` above the button. Type enough text so that it starts to scroll down as it's supposed to, many lines of text.
3. Click the same button again which is now titled "Save". Now a non editable `JTextPane` will be displayed in the `JScrollPane` instead of the `JTextArea`.
4. See how the `JSCrollPane` resized?

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private final JTextArea textArea;
    private final JTextPane textPane;
    private final JButton editButton;
    private String text;

    private boolean isEditing = false;


    public Main() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setVisible(false);
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);
        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isEditing = !isEditing;
                textPane.setVisible(!isEditing);
                textArea.setVisible(isEditing);
                if(isEditing) {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
                    editButton.setText("Save");
                }
                else {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);
                    editButton.setText("Edit");
                    text = textArea.getText();
                }
                textPane.setText(text);
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints bag = new GridBagConstraints();
        bag.gridx = 0;
        bag.gridy = 0;
        bag.gridwidth = 3;
        bag.gridheight = 1;
        bag.weightx = 1.0;
        bag.weighty = 1.0;
        bag.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        bag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        bag.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        add(scrollPane, bag);

        bag = new GridBagConstraints();
        bag.gridx = 1;
        bag.gridy = 1;
        bag.gridwidth = 1;
        bag.gridheight = 1;
        bag.weightx = 1.0;
        bag.weighty = 1.0;
        add(editButton, bag);

        setSize(1000, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Main ui = new Main();
        });
    }
}
```

PS: I am swapping to a `JTextPane` because I am planning to render markdown text which I have excluded to keep the example simple. I am using JDK 8u231

I have tried saving the original size and setting it using `setPreferredSize` and `setMaximumSize` when I swap them out but it did not solve my problem. I would also like to keep it resizable for when the window resizes.

Update: I need to use the `GridBag` layout because I have a `JPanel` on which I draw by overriding the `paint()` function just above it

Comment: *"Type enough text so that it starts to scroll down as it's supposed to, many lines of text."* Yeah .. nah. Add a button that can add a line of text. My interest in solving this is purely academic, and not enough to type one line, let alone enough to make it scroll. BTW - the little further attention I paid to this made me think that a `CardLayout` might be better for swapping between the text area and text pane.

Comment: You can just type single lettered lines which is what I do, takes 5 seconds to make it scroll. Thanks I will look at the `CradLayout`

Comment: Why are you switching out a JTextPane and a JTextArea?

Comment: I want to use the `JTextPane` to render Markdown and use the `JTextArea` to edit it. I have omitted the rendering from the code to keep it simple and runnable by only using standard JDK in the example. So the `JTextPane` contains html that was rendered from the markdown in the `JTextArea` if that makes sense.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Using a `CardLayout` is a cleaner solution than calling `setViewportView` every time, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: *I need to use the GridBag layout* - no you don't. You still haven't grasped the concept that you can use multiple panels and each panel can have a different layout manager. You need to understand how each layout manager works and how spaces is allocated to each component as the frame is resized.

Comment: I did try what you suggested @camickr. I placed the `JTextPane` and `JTextArea` in their own `BorderLayout`s, I placed those in the `CardLayout`, I placed the panel with the `CardLayout` in the `GridLayout`, it still grows when switching them out... This is to be expected given what you said: "Components added to the `CENTER` grows". So I should use some other layout that doesn't grow?

Do we really need to have a million panels and layouts instead of one single layout with rules for each component like in other frameworks? This seems like such an unnecessary waste.

Comment: *it still grows when switching them out...* - What? All the components added to the CardLayout are given the same size. This is what you want. You want to be able to swap between the JTextPane/JTextArea, in the same space. They will only grow if the frame size is changed. If you want a single layout then use the GridBagLayout or GroupLayout. They are far more complicated to use because you need to specify the rules (constraints) for every panel. Most experienced developers prefer logically group components and nest panels.

Comment: This discussion is going nowhere as it appears you still don't understand the concepts of layout managers and their flexibility when used properly. If where given a working example that solved your initial problem. If you have additional requirements, then you need to post a better question with a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem you have implementing these requirements. This is my last comment to this question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Swing components should determine their own preferred size. You should NOT be hardcoding random sizes. Then the layout manager can use this information.

The easiest way to do this is to give a hint to the JTextArea for the number of rows/columns it should contain by using:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 40);
```

You then use the appropriate layout manager to allow the components to dynamically resize as the frame size changes. I would use the BorderLayout for this. Then after you add the components to the frame you pack the frame.

A basic solution might be:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main5 extends JFrame {
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private final JTextArea textArea;
    private final JTextPane textPane;
    private final JButton editButton;
    private String text;

    private boolean isEditing = false;


    public Main5() {
//        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
//        textArea = new JTextArea();
//       textArea.setVisible(false);
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        textArea = new JTextArea(15, 40);
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setPreferredSize( textArea.getPreferredSize() );
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);

        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isEditing = !isEditing;
                textPane.setVisible(!isEditing);
//                textArea.setVisible(isEditing);
                if(isEditing) {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
                    editButton.setText("Save");
                    textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
                else {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);
                    editButton.setText("Edit");
                    text = textArea.getText();
                }
                textPane.setText(text);
            }
        });
/*
        GridBagConstraints bag = new GridBagConstraints();
        bag.gridx = 0;
        bag.gridy = 0;
        bag.gridwidth = 3;
        bag.gridheight = 1;
        bag.weightx = 1.0;
        bag.weighty = 1.0;
        bag.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        bag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        bag.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        add(scrollPane, bag);

        bag = new GridBagConstraints();
        bag.gridx = 1;
        bag.gridy = 1;
        bag.gridwidth = 1;
        bag.gridheight = 1;
        bag.weightx = 1.0;
        bag.weighty = 1.0;
        add(editButton, bag);
*/
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.add(editButton);
        add(wrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

//        setSize(1000, 500);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Main5 ui = new Main5();
        });
    }
}
```

Even if you convert this to use a CardLayout it will still work because the size of the card panel is determined by the size of the largest panel added to it.

Comment: Hello, and thanks, I agree that I should not be hardcoding random sizes, I would have liked to avoid it. However did you try out your solution in my example? How do I set the number of rows when switching to the `JTextPane`? I also need the layout to be  `GridBag` because I have a `JPanel` on which I draw above it, sorry maybe I should've mentioned it in the question.

Comment: *How do I set the number of rows when switching to the JTextPane?* - I don't understand your question? Did you try the code? There is no need to set the rows of the text pane.  It will automatically be the same size as the text area.

Comment: Yes I did try it, when I use a `GridPane` instead of a `BorderPane` it still has the same problem when I switch to the `JTextPane`. But as I mentioned I need to use a `GridBag`. Just using a `BorderPane` instead of a `GridPane` seems to just avoid the problem and not solving it. I have also tried having the `JTextPane` and `JTextArea` inside a `CardLayout` which also does not solve the problem.

Comment: There is no such thing ad a GridPane. It won't work because the point of a `GridLayout` is to make all the components the same size. The reason I used the `BorderLayout` is to take advantage of the the rules of the BorderLayout so that your text components have a fixed size and the the other components added to the CENTER grow in size. It does NOT avoid the problem, it SOLVES the problem because it uses the BorderLayout the way it was designed to be used. Panels are designed to be nested and use different layout mangers based on your requirements.

Comment: And no a CardLayout won't solve the problem, that is NOT its job. Its job is to just display two or more components on the same space of the frame, one at a time. You still have not stated why the solution here doesn't work. It does exactly as you asked. If you have a different requirement, then you need to post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your requirement. We can't guess what you are attempting to do. The question has been answered based on your original requirement.

Comment: I have updated the question earlier stating that I need to use a `GridLayout` because I have various other components in there such as a `JPanel` on which I paint on. I did not include those because I wanted to keep it minimal, the example demonstrates the problem I am having. I am sorry for using the wrong word `GridPane`, I use both JavaFX and Swing daily and got them mixed up. So what you are saying is that I should put it in a `BorderLayout`, put that in a `CardLayout` (to switch between them), then put that into my `GridLayout`?

Answer (score -2):

Ok I have found a solution. If I set the preferred size of the `JScrollPane` to some fixed value that is not too large then it still remains the size I want it to be and it doesn't grow vertically. It also resizes with the window when I resize the window. See the code below and thank you to Andrew Thompson in the comments for suggesting a `CardLayout`.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private final JTextArea textArea;
    private final JTextPane textPane;
    private final JButton editButton;
    private String text;
    private final JPanel cardPanel;
    private final CardLayout cards;

    private boolean isEditing = false;
    
    public Main() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        cards = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel = new JPanel();
        cardPanel.setLayout(cards);
        cardPanel.add(textPane);
        cardPanel.add(textArea);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(cardPanel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 50));
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isEditing = !isEditing;
                if(isEditing) {
                    editButton.setText("Save");
                }
                else {
                    editButton.setText("Edit");
                    text = textArea.getText();
                }
                textPane.setText(text);
                cards.next(cardPanel);
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints bag = new GridBagConstraints();
        bag.gridx = 0;
        bag.gridy = 0;
        bag.gridwidth = 3;
        bag.gridheight = 1;
        bag.weightx = 1.0;
        bag.weighty = 1.0;
        bag.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        bag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        bag.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        add(scrollPane, bag);

        bag = new GridBagConstraints();
        bag.gridx = 1;
        bag.gridy = 1;
        bag.gridwidth = 1;
        bag.gridheight = 1;
        bag.weightx = 1.0;
        bag.weighty = 1.0;
        add(editButton, bag);

        setSize(1000, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Main ui = new Main();
        });
    }
}
```

I have added:
`scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 50));`

I don't actually want it to be 50 but fortunately it doesn't make it 50 pixels high. I just wanted it to stay more or less half the height of the window as it was in the beginning.

Comment: Don't use random hardcoded sizes. Swing components should be able to determine their own preferred size. What is 50. Is that 2, 3, 4 or 5 rows of text? As a user I like to see complete rows of text without the text only being half visible. A JtextArea know what the height of each row of text will be so it can accurately calculate the height of the text area.

Comment: I agree, random sizes is a no go, but it cannot determine it's own size in my case, it just keeps on growing and making the other components/rows in the `GridBag` smaller, even if I call `setMinimumSize()` on them. 50 gives me 12 rows, which is plenty, enough to fill the entire area available to it. As I said in the solution, it is not actually 50 pixels in height but it solves the problem.